# Jhipster add field to user entity

Tags: jhipster

I'm working on a project based on Jhipster,and i will update update user entity; i will add external field to user entity for example add birthday field to my user entity.
how i can do it?
thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Let's see some code. Be as specific as possible. Read this page for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in JHipster to help you doing so.
It's up to you to modify the generated code for your needs:

- add your field to the User entity and UserDTO
- create a new Liquibase changelog to add a new column in user table
- modify html form and controller

Comment: Read the Liquibase docs and see what is already in your src/main/resources/config/liquibase folder